# Length method is not working in c#

Tags: c#

I want to make a comparison between a table in mysql and 1 table in sql server using the cod below. But the Length method i tried to use is marked up as an error. What should I do please I need a little help. Thank you !

```
int lengthClienti = MySqlSetClienti.Tables["clienti"].Length;

int columnClienti = 4;

for (int i = 0; i <= lengthClienti - 1; i++)//row
{
    for (int j = 0; i <= columnClienti; j++)//column
    {
        if (SqlDataSet.Tables["ClientiImporti"].Rows[i][j].ToString() == MySqlSetClienti.Tables["clienti"].Rows[i][j].ToString())
        {
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: What is type of this property?

Comment: `MySqlSetClienti` is a DataSet...?

Comment: It's not working because there is no ".Length" property on System.Data.DataTable, intellisense and compile error would give you a hint on that..

Answer (score 5):

You want to include Rows;

```
 MySqlSetClienti.Tables["clienti"].Rows.Count
```